# Storing objects in vector: better to store the object or a pointer to it?

Tags: c++, stl

I have objects that I'm using throughout application lifetime: they are never destroyed. I'm storing them in vector:

```
declaration:
    std::vector<DoubleValue> bidDealIndexes;

construction:
    bidDealIndexes(Instrument::InstrumentsCount())

 usage:
    DoubleValue& v = bidDealIndexes[0];
```

Alternatively I can store pointers:

```
declaration:
    std::vector<DoubleValue*> bidDealIndexes;

construction:
    for (int i = 0; i < Instrument::InstrumentsCount(); i++) {
        bidDealIndexes.push_back(new DoubleValue());
    }

 usage:
    DoubleValue* v = bidDealIndexes[0];
```

The question is which is preferable? Should one (or both) of these options should be avoided?

Comment: Are you using c++11? Because the `vector<T>(N) ` constructor you are using no longer copies in c++11.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are always preferred, and pointers should be avoided unless you need them. The main argument is that one should not complicate things without reason, and pointers introduce complication. In your example there is no need for pointers.

Comment: the main question is how allocation happens. how vector allocates objects? and how `new` allocates objects? probably vector is not good enough?

Comment: In most of the cases std::vector and storing values - not pointers - works and thus is preferable. Using other solutions - like pointers (smart or raw), std::array etc. is just complication, which must be justified. Do you have any problems with vector storing values in your case? If so, present them. If not, just use vector with values and do not complicate unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

## Storage by Value

Storing an object directly into a vector (or other STL container) is best left to primitive types when possible.  This is because each insertion actually creates a *copy* of the object being stored.  If you are storing a class object, such as your `DoubleValue` type, then the copy constructor is called each time you `push_back`.  If the copy constructor is cheap (i.e. there is little storage inside the class and the copy constructor does little or no work), then storage by value will make your life simple.  For more complex objects, storage by value may not even be possible.  For example, `iostream`s cannot be copied, so they cannot be placed into a vector.  For classes with expensive copy constructors, storage by value will slow down execution and increase memory footprint.

**Summary:** Use for lightweight objects

## Storage by *raw* Pointer

With the advent of C++11 (and some other 3rd party libraries like boost), storage via raw pointer is discouraged due to the complications of tracking ownership and object lifetime.  This is a whole other topic area that's been well covered in Stack Overflow.  If you cannot use C++11, then take care when storing by raw pointer.  This can be more performant than storage by value, and allows for storage of object types that cannot be copied (such as iostreams).

**Summary:**  Use for heavyweight objects when smart pointers are not available

## Storage by *smart* pointer

C++11 introduces smart pointers in the form of `std::shared_ptr` and their ilk.  These manage the lifetime of the object through reference counting and follow the RAII (resource acquisition is initialization) pattern.  The net-effect is that from your perspective they work like raw pointers but you don't have to worry about:

1. pointers to deleted objects
2. who is responsible for deleting the object

I don't know if `shared_ptr` is most appropriate in your situation, but the usage of smart pointers looks something like:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DoubleValue> > bigDealIndexes;
bigDealIndexes.push_back(std::shared_ptr<DoubleValue>(new DoubleValue));

std::cout << "Value of first big deal: " << *(bigDealIndexes[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Member 'a':              " << bigDealIndexes[0]->a << std::endl;
```

**Summary:** Use for heavyweight objects when using C++11, boost, or a similar library

Comment: Only use shared_ptr for shared ownership, not just because the object is heavy.

Comment: almost all my object has "disabled" copy-construct, i don't like to copy objects

Comment: @javapowered: That might be leaning a bit too much to java in C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think so, because if you don't know the exact machanics in C++ you can't say when and how often the copy constructor is called. So If you don't have a compiler which does no return value optimization you quickly get 2 or more copies for just one line of code.
e.g. MyType tmp = getValue(); // def => MyType getValue();

Comment: @Nicoretti: You can always use a bad compiler, but if it is that bad then you should really avoid all of STL too. Performance there somewhat depends on the compiler soing such optimisations.

Comment: Storage by value is not just for lightweight objects. We now have `emplace_back`,  RVO, move semantics,  copy-elision,  etc which all allow us to use a vector of large objects without paying a performance penalty.

Comment: @Deduplicator There may be more appropriate semantics than shared_ptr depending on the code.  As @RichardHodges points out above, `std::unique_ptr` may be more appropriate if the object is only going to live inside of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, if your object is a POD and your vector is less than several thousand items long, you will get better performance by using a

```
std::vector<DoubleValue>
```

. Copies are *very* cheap compared to cache misses.

If DoubleValue is (very) big or noncopyable and the vector is also the controller of the object's lifetime, then use

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DoubleValue>>
```

If DoubleValue is big and you would prefer by-value style (you should), then you could consider implementing DoubleValue using the pimpl idiom and making it copyable or moveable which would allow you to store it in a std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector is constant-length, consider using `std::array` instead.
Otherwise, stick to a `std::vector` of element. You might want to call `reserve()` before storing the elements to avoid superfluous copying, if you have to insert a whole batch of elements.

***For experts only:*** If the objects are expensive to move though, and managing the added members lifetime is **somebody elses problem** (e.g they stay alive until end of program), then you might consider storing pointers as an optimisation. Still, only consider that after careful measurement and consideration.

Comment: my vectors are constant-length but this constant is calculated at runtime.

Comment: Ok, that means the first and last option do not apply, so go with the `standard::vector<DoubleValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11, storing by value like you have done would definitely be preferred. In c++03, I would probably still prefer storing by value unless performance measurements showed it to be a problem.

In c++11 the `vector<T>(N)` constructor you are using was changed to use value initialization instead of making `N` copies.

Storing by value is simpler and will probably perform better in your case. If performance is a concern measure it and see.

**Edit**: I did some crude measurements comparing [by-value](http://ideone.com/xCryN2), [raw-pointers](http://ideone.com/UfGTTJ) & [unique_ptr](http://ideone.com/bEZI2w) and by-value came out top.